# Bootstrap Carousel raising images and dropping back down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap carousel and have it functioning except for one bit. Whenever the slide changes, the new slide is twice as high as the old. When the slide becomes active the image drops down into the correct position.

Here's what I've got.

```
    <div id="carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <!-- <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li> -->
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img alt="First slide" src="images/surf2.png" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 15px;">
                <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h1>One Microsoft Story for Healthcare</h1>
                    <p><a href="#" >Connect ></a> &nbsp<a href="#" >Request a Demo ></a>  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="item">
                 <img alt="First slide" src="images/tablet2.png" style="padding-top: 15px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                 <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
                     <h1>One Microsoft Story for Healthcare</h1>
                     <p><a href="#" >Connect ></a> &nbsp<a href="#" >Request a Demo ></a>  </p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Link to JSFiddle will be helpful.

Comment: works perfectly for me: https://jsfiddle.net/3qLqhebk/

Comment: Should this be in the main container of the page? or should it be set apart in its own container or or row?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and deleting the 'slide' class seemed to do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

BGiezen's answer is good but try adding 'carousel-fade' after removing 'slide'
It looks better.
Click [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#crossfade) for docs

Answer (score -1):

Change top position from 0 to 10px in...

```
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```